# Puma crashes after restarting delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have issue with delayed_job working with puma and rails 4. Puma is crashing after restarting delayed_job and I am not able to find out why...

Here is the only relevant log I have:

```
Mar 28 11:19:01 localhost CRON[30015]: (deployer) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/xxx/production/releases/20140324122442 && RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job restart >> /var/xxx/production/releases/20140324122442/log/cron.log 2>&1')
    Mar 28 11:19:08 localhost kernel: [270318.742814] select 1 (init), adj 0, size 225, to kill
    Mar 28 11:19:08 localhost kernel: [270318.742824] select 789 (whoopsie), adj 0, size 345, to kill
    Mar 28 11:19:08 localhost kernel: [270318.742826] select 905 (postgres), adj 0, size 646, to kill
    Mar 28 11:19:08 localhost kernel: [270318.742829] select 27536 (bash), adj 0, size 1672, to kill
    Mar 28 11:19:08 localhost kernel: [270318.742832] select 28704 (bash), adj 0, size 1673, to kill
    Mar 28 11:19:08 localhost kernel: [270318.742834] select 29660 (ruby), adj 0, size 21780, to kill
    Mar 28 11:19:08 localhost kernel: [270318.742836] select 29989 (ruby), adj 0, size 24133, to kill
    Mar 28 11:19:08 localhost kernel: [270318.742838] send sigkill to 29989 (ruby), adj 0, size 24133
```

Comment: where exactly is the log of puma crashing?

Comment: It crashed at 11:19:08... I have nothing interesting in other logs. I think it's killed with sigkill, but I don't know why. Log is always the same and it happens when I try to restart delayed_job

Comment: i can't follow your thoughts